# List comprehensions, list of lists and list concatenation

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This is my code

```
[temp.append(i.get_hot_post(3)) for i in node_list]
[hot_posts+i.sort(key=sort_by_rate) for i in temp ]
```

get_hot_posts() return a list of 3 items this way

```
return recent_posts[0:amount-1]
```

it could be that the list is shorter than 3 elements and it probably mess the things around but go on

```
[temp.append(i.get_hot_post(3)) for i in node_list]
```

after this command, in "temp" i have a list of lists and it's fine.

But when it executes

```
[hot_posts+i.sort(key=sort_by_rate) for i in temp ]
```

it gives this error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list
```

Comment: The answers below are good, here is documentation on [List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant `sorted(i)`, no? `i.sort()` does the sorting in-place and returns nothing.

Also, why would you like to do [hot_posts + ...]? This will not store the values in the hot_posts, so the operation is meaningless, unless you assign the result to a new variable.

I suspect you wanted to do something like

```
temp = [i.get_hot_post(3) for i in node_list]
hot_posts = [sorted(i, key=sort_by_rate) for i in temp]
```

Although I have no idea what your last line is supposed to do. Now it just sorts each of these small lists of three and that's it.

Comment: It is supposed to concatenate all the elements in the list hot_posts. Thanks for the advice on sort(), it's the first time i use it.

Comment: then i think it should look like this: [post for i in temp for post in i], see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 4):

List method `sort` returns `None` (just changing list). You can use `sorted()` function instead.

PS.

```
[temp.append(i.get_hot_post(3)) for i in node_list]
```

is not very good idea, cause you will have a list of `None`. Possible variants:

```
temp += [i.get_hot_post(3) for i in node_list]
```

or even

```
from operator import methodcaller 
temp += map(methodcaller(get_hot_post, 3), node_list)
```